# Linux fetchmail POP3 connection error

Tags: linux, slackware

Slackware OS, trying to setup fetchmail

I have coded this .fetchmailrc file:

```
set daemon 600 //fetches mail every hour or 60 minutes.
set logfile /root/fetchmail.log

poll 10.200.***.** protocol POP3
user "bob" password "bob" is "bob" here preconnect "date>>/root/fetchmail.log"

ssl
no rewrite
keep
```

It worked before but now it is failing to retrieve mail, i checked the fetchmail.log file and i get this error:

```
Thu Nov 5 10:15:32 GMT 2015
fetchmail: connection errors for this poll:
name 0: connection to 10.200.***.**:pop3s [10.200.***.**/995] failed: Connection refused.
fetchmail: POP3 connection to 10.200.***.** failed: Connection refused
fetchmail: Query status=2 (SOCKET)
```

I've reset the daemons, ended the process and no progress.

Comment: what output `telnet 10.200.***.** 995` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on a Mageia 5 Linux. Apparently, I
solved it by redoing network configuration, which the Mageia can do
with a single click on the relevant Configure button in the Network
Center window.

I did not touch my .fetchmailrc file.